# Safari Push Notifications - window.safari is not present

Tags: javascript, safari, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, osx-mavericks

Implementing [Safari Push Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/PushNotifications/PushNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013225-CH3-SW1), I tried to follow their example:

```
// Ensure that the user can receive Safari Push Notifications.
if ('safari' in window && 'pushNotification' in window.safari) {
    ...
}
```

My test HTML file with the code below resides on OSX 10.9.x Maverics, and I open it in Safari 7.x on the same machine.
Notification preference pane is present in Safari, so I assume the system has support for the Safari Push Notifications.

However, DOM window object does not contain `'safari'`, as can be seen in Safari's Web Inspector. Consequently, `window.safari.pushNotification` is not available.
*window.navigator.userAgent*: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/536.30.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.5 Safari/536.30.1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML='safari' in window;
      document.getElementById("id2").innerHTML=window.safari;
    }
  </script>
  <h2>Safari Push Notifications</h2>
  <div>'safari' in window ? <span id="id1"></span></div>
  <div>window.safari ? <span id="id2"></span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can the client gain access to pushNotification?

Comment: Actually, `window.safari` is present in DOM - when the content in Safari browser is served by a web server. In my initial tests, I put the code above in a stand-alone HTML file, opened it in Safari - and `window.safari` was not there.